# Show a specific part of a findstr

Tags: batch-file, cmd, set, findstr

This is a command to show the name of the connected Wi-Fi:

```
Netsh WLAN show interfaces | findstr Profile
```

Result :

```
Profile                : Mywifi_5G
```

How can I show just the `Mywifi_5G`? Like this:

```
Mywifi_5G
```

I need it because I want to put the result into a variable of a Batch File.

Comment: `for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('Netsh WLAN show interfaces ^| findstr Profile') do set "variable=%%a"`

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps... I Tried the Code given here but it didnt work for me... Anyways you try it out..https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120731-00/?p=7003#comments

Comment: It was very useful, I managed to finish my script.Thank you a lot : )

Comment: Would you mind upvoting the answer? it would be a great help  :) ❤️❤️

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for **tabby.sl**'s answer, I finished the script.

It is to get the SSID and password of the connected Wi-Fi.

Batch Script :

```
@ECHO OFF
  
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%i IN ('netsh wlan show interfaces ^| findstr /C:"Perfil"') DO SET SSID=%%i

FOR /f "tokens=5" %%i IN ('netsh wlan show profile %SSID% key"="clear ^| findstr /C:"Chave"') DO SET PASSWORD=%%i

ECHO --------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO.
ECHO            SSID : %SSID%
ECHO.
ECHO            PASSWORD : %PASSWORD%
ECHO.
ECHO --------------------------------------------------------------------

PAUSE
```

**Notes** : "Perfil" and "Chave" are words from cmd in Portuguese ( Brazil ).
Perfil = Profile
Chave = Key
The number in "tokens=" will depend of the system language.